# UVA 3n+1 submission error

Tags: python

When I submit the code it gives me a runtime error but when I run it in my jupyter python it works fine.  Anyone know what it gives me a runtime error?
Edit: Here's link to problem and input [ehere][https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36]

```
from sys import stdin

def main():
    curr_line=stdin.readline()
    while curr_line!=None:
        x = []
        curr_line = curr_line.split()
        num1 = int(curr_line[0])
        num2 = int(curr_line[1])
        index = 0
        for i in range(num1, num2+1):
            counter = 1
            while i != 1:
                if i % 2  == 1:
                    i = 3*i + 1
                else:
                    i = i/2
                counter += 1
            x.append(counter)
            index += 1            
        print(num1, num2, max(x), sep = " ")
        curr_line=stdin.readline()
    return 
main()
```

Comment: Please submit the runtime error.

Comment: what do you mean by "submit the code"

Comment: You don't sanitize that the `curr_line` has at least two elements after the `split()`, and moreover, if so, that they are convertible to `int`: if I were I to speculate, then I would assume that `int(curr_line[1])` yields the runtime error.

Comment: @csl I can't.  UVA doesn't say what error it just states "runtime error"

Comment: @dfri The text that is read in by UVA should be "num1 num2" (separated by space where variable names are actual random numbers).  Could you elaborate why whta I'm doing doesn't work?

Comment: @JohnW try wrapping everything in a `try` block and explicitly print any error caught.

Comment: @dfri I can't because UVA wouldn't print any error.  You basically submit your code and it tells you if it works or not.  How do I get stdin.readline() to take userinput rather than system input?